# Design time error in all solution forms

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik

I've strange design time error suddenly appear in all winforms in my solution and here is the stack trace I got:

```
at System.Resources.Tools.StronglyTypedResourceBuilder.Create(IDictionary resourceList, String baseName, String generatedCodeNamespace, String resourcesNamespace, CodeDomProvider codeProvider, Boolean internalClass, String[]& unmatchable)
at System.Resources.Tools.StronglyTypedResourceBuilder.Create(IDictionary resourceList, String baseName, String generatedCodeNamespace, CodeDomProvider codeProvider, Boolean internalClass, String[]& unmatchable)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.ResXGlobalObject.BuildType()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.ResXGlobalObject.GetObjectType()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.GlobalType.get_ObjectType()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.ResXGlobalObject.get_Children()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.ResXGlobalObjectProvider.CreateGlobalObjectsForItem(ProjectItem item, GlobalObjectCollection oldObjects, GlobalObjectCollection newObjects, ITypeResolutionService typeResolver)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.ResXGlobalObjectProvider.CreateGlobalObjectsForItem(ProjectItem item, GlobalObjectCollection oldObjects, GlobalObjectCollection newObjects, ITypeResolutionService typeResolver)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.ResXGlobalObjectProvider.CreateGlobalObjects(Project project)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.ResXGlobalObjectProvider.GetGlobalObjectsCore(Project project, Type baseType)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.GlobalObjectProvider.GetGlobalObjects(Project project, Type baseType)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.GlobalObjectService.GetGlobalObjects(Type baseType)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.AggregateTypeResolutionService.GetTypeFromGlobalObjects(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.AggregateTypeResolutionService.GetType(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.AggregateTypeResolutionService.GetType(String name)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.DesignerHost.System.ComponentModel.Design.IDesignerHost.GetType(String typeName)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomDesignerLoader.EnsureDocument(IDesignerSerializationManager manager)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager manager)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager serializationManager)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.BasicDesignerLoader.BeginLoad(IDesignerLoaderHost host)
```

I use VS 2012 with syncfusion and telerik as external component.

thanx

Comment: What was the error message?

Comment: Try to identify the actual error and post it here instead of the whole error stack. StackOverflow is not a garbage collector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this happen with having multiple 3rd party vendor controls installed. Can you try to uninstall one of them, restarting VS and give it a shot again?

Answer (score 0):

I have to solve this problem,add new `Windows Form` by right clicking on solution and Add New Item and then delete it.